# how to choose appropriate resource file

Tags: asp.net, localization

I'm creating a multi-language website. I have resource files "lang-en" , "lang-fr" , "lang-fa".

now i want to use it like:

```
<a href="#"><%= Resources.SelectedLanguage.signup %></a>
```

but I can only choose like:

```
<a href="#"><% Resources.lang-en.signup %></a>
<a href="#"><% Resources.lang-fa.signup %></a>
<a href="#"><% Resources.lang-fr.signup %></a>
```

how can I use a variable to select the language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it. If you know a better way please tell to revise my program.

```
     ResourceManager rm;
    switch(lang){
case "en":
rm = new ResourceManager(typeof( Resources.lang_en));
case "fr": 
rm = new ResourceManager(typeof( Resources.lang_fr));
case "fa":
rm = new ResourceManager(typeof( Resources.lang_fa));
}
```

and now it can be used like:

```
<a href="#"><%= rm.GetString("signup") %></a>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly but you should no need to do any of these. You set the current user culture to a locale and asp.net will handle the rest, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f(v=vs.80).aspx.

Comment: this has done the same as I did, the difference is I did all in one page getting the language by QueryString but this has done it with separating pages for each language.